# How to get current time into specific format in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the current time in a format like this:

9:00pm

Should be in AM/PM format and be based on users timezone.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good libraries for formatting JavaScript Dates.

I've had good luck with the one from Matt Kruse

[Javascript Library Home page](http://javascripttoolbox.com/lib/date/)